# TP-Link TL-WN851N not recognised or working

Tags: 16.04, drivers, wireless, xubuntu, atheros

I just moved house and our new house doesnt have ethernet ports in the walls so I needed to install a wireless card into my xubuntu file server running 16.04 lts AMDx64

I'm currently connected using a usb wireless dongle @ 150mbps

Wireless card:
TP-Link TL-WN851N (Wireless N 300mbps)

I managed to get it to recognise an unclaimed network using

```
sudo lshw -C network

*-network UNCLAIMED
   description: Network controller
   product: Tul Corporation / PowerColor
   vendor: Tul Corporation / PowerColor
   physical id: 6
   bus info: pci@0000:01:06.0
   version: 01
   width: 32 bits
   clock: 66MHz
   capabilities: pm bus_master cap_list
   configuration: latency=64
   resources: memory:fbaf0000-fbafffff
```

I cant find the Ath9k driver and my backports are enabled.

```
rfkill list all
```

Gives no results

Can someone please help me.

Comment: Could you give the result of `lsusb` and `sudo iw dev`? if your USB device as an atheros chipset it requires ath9k_htc (ath9k is for internal cards). The driver is present by default, it should work out of the box...

Comment: I believe it is a PCI device. Please edit your question to add the result of the terminal commands: `lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A3` and also: `sudo modprobe ath9k`

Comment: Ups... You are right chili555: it is a PCI device, not an USB device. So the `lsusub` command given before is not useful; the `lspci` command you gave is the one relevant here.

Comment: ##### lspci #############################

01:06.0 Network controller [0280]: Tul Corporation / PowerColor Device [148c:0029] (rev 01)
 Subsystem: Tul Corporation / PowerColor Device [148c:2091]

02:00.0 RAID bus controller [0104]: Adaptec Series 8 12G SAS/PCIe 3 [9005:028d] (rev 01)

04:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10ec:8168] (rev 01)
 Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [1043:8385]
 Kernel driver in use: r8169

Comment: it is a PCI device and I cant remember the code but i couldnt find Ath9k driver on my machine

Comment: It's like it can't even see the device.
I tried searching for "Aditional Drivers" and it just lists a cpu driver that's already in use

Comment: `Network controller: Tul Corporation / PowerColor Device 0029 (rev 01)` is a Radeon gaming graphics company

Comment: FYI **kcdtv** `sudo iw dev` gives no result

Answer (score 0):

So according to [WifiDocs](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HardwareSupportComponentsWirelessNetworkCardsTP-Link)

> Tested on Ubuntu 11.04 Due to a kernel/driver issue, download rate is slow (max 300kiB/s with 802.11g) and slower than upload. Installing wireless-compat didn't help

I suspect this card doesnt work with Xubuntu at all.

Looks like I need to buy a new Wifi card!